# transform: translateY Not Working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, transform

translateY is not working in safari browser, though it works fine in all other browsers. I have played around with the white spacing, and even tried -webkit-transform:-webkit-translateY(-420px) with no luck. Am I missing a step? I've never had this issue before.

```
.animate-up {
  -webkit-transorm:translateY(-420px);
  -moz-transorm:translateY(-420px);
  -ms-transorm:translateY(-420px);
  -o-transorm:translateY(-420px);
  transform:translateY(-420px)
}
```

http://codepen.io/jessekevon/pen/myjzjb?editors=010

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this one, as I believe it's because you forgot the **f** in **transform**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot **f** in **transform**

```
.animate-up {
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-420px);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-420px);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-420px);
  -o-transform:translateY(-420px);
  transform:translateY(-420px);
}
```

**it works in other browsers because**

```
transform:translateY(-420px)
```

is spelled correctly.

Comment: Oh my gosh, biggest 'doh' moment ever. Thanks for the extra set of eyes, I appreciate it!

Comment: :) you can accept answer it will help me to help others! Thanks